# Solving a ODEs: Modeling a physical system with equations of motion

Tags: python, matplotlib, system, physics, differential-equations

im quite new at this world, actually I came from physics and found the need of learning a little bit of python to grow my level... I´ve been coding this for days to solve this system of equations to model a system, and I´m still not able to make it run, it always raises an error of:

```
Cell In[8], line 8, in f(X, t, m, g, alpha, I1, I3, d1, d2, r1, r2, mu)
      6 def f(X, t, m, g, alpha, I1, I3, d1, d2, r1, r2, mu):
      7     # Unpack the variables from X
----> 8     xCM, yCM, phi, omega3, N1, N2 = X
     11     # Calculate the k values for each wheel
     12     k1x = -mu * np.linalg.norm(np.arctan((yCM + r1*omega3*np.cos(phi) - d1*phi_dot*np.cos(phi)*np.sin(psi)) / (xCM - r1*omega3*np.sin(phi) + d1*phi_dot*np.sin(phi)*np.sin(psi)))) * np.sign(xCM - r1*omega3*np.sin(phi) + d1*phi_dot*np.sin(phi)*np.sin(psi))

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable float object
```

The code is this:

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def f(X, t, m, g, alpha, I1, I3, d1, d2, r1, r2, mu):
    # Unpack the variables from X
    xCM, yCM, phi, omega3, N1, N2 = X
    
    
    # Calculate the k values for each wheel
    k1x = -mu * np.linalg.norm(np.arctan((yCM + r1*omega3*np.cos(phi) - d1*phi_dot*np.cos(phi)*np.sin(psi)) / (xCM - r1*omega3*np.sin(phi) + d1*phi_dot*np.sin(phi)*np.sin(psi)))) * np.sign(xCM - r1*omega3*np.sin(phi) + d1*phi_dot*np.sin(phi)*np.sin(psi))
    k1y = -mu * np.linalg.norm(np.arctan((yCM + r1*omega3*np.cos(phi) - d1*phi_dot*np.cos(phi)*np.sin(psi)) / (xCM - r1*omega3*np.sin(phi) + d1*phi_dot*np.sin(phi)*np.sin(psi)))) * np.sign(xCM + r1*omega3*np.sin(phi) - d1*phi_dot*np.sin(phi)*np.sin(psi))
    k2x = -mu * np.linalg.norm(np.arctan((yCM + r2*omega3*np.cos(phi) + d2*phi_dot*np.cos(phi)*np.sin(psi)) / (xCM - r2*omega3*np.sin(phi) - d2*phi_dot*np.sin(phi)*np.sin(psi)))) * np.sign(xCM - r2*omega3*np.sin(phi) - d2*phi_dot*np.sin(phi)*np.sin(psi))
    k2y = -mu * np.linalg.norm(np.arctan((yCM + r2*omega3*np.cos(phi) + d2*phi_dot*np.cos(phi)*np.sin(psi)) / (xCM - r2*omega3*np.sin(phi) - d2*phi_dot*np.sin(phi)*np.sin(psi)))) * np.sign(xCM + r2*omega3*np.sin(phi) + d2*phi_dot*np.sin(phi)*np.sin(psi))

    xCM_dot = phi_dot*(r1*k1y - r2*k2y)/m
    yCM_dot = (m*g*np.sin(alpha) + N1*k1x + N2*k2x - phi_dot**2*(r1*k1x + r2*k2x))/m
    phi_dot = omega3
    psi_dot = omega3*np.cos(phi)/np.sin(psi)
    omega3_dot = ((r1*k1y - r2*k2y)*np.cos(phi) - (r1*k1x + r2*k2x)*np.sin(phi) + (d1*k1y - d2*k2y)*np.cos(psi)*np.sin(phi) - (d1*k1x + d2*k2x)*np.sin(psi)*np.sin(phi) - I1*phi_dot*omega3*np.sin(phi) + I3*psi_dot*omega3*np.cos(phi))/I3

    # Return the derivatives as a numpy array
    return np.array([xCM_dot, yCM_dot, phi_dot, omega3_dot, N1, N2])

X0 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) # initial conditions for [xCM, yCM, phi, psi, omega3]
t_span = [0, 10] # time interval to solve over
t_eval = np.linspace(t_span[0], t_span[1], 1000) # times to evaluate the solution at

m = 1 # mass of the unicycle
g = 9.81 # acceleration due to gravity
alpha = np.pi/4 # slope angle
I1 = 0.1 # moment of inertia about the x-axis
I3 = 0.2 # moment of inertia about the z-axis
d1 = 0.3 # distance between the center of mass and the axis of rotation for the left wheel
d2 = 0.3 # distance between the center of mass and the axis of rotation for the right wheel
r1 = 0.3 # radius of the left wheel
r2 = 0.3 # radius of the right wheel
mu = 0.2 # coefficient of friction
psi = 0.3

sol = solve_ivp(f, t_span, X0, t_eval=t_eval, args=(m, g, alpha, I1, I3, d1, d2, r1, r2, mu))
```

If anyone can help me. I will be eternally grateful, I´ve been trying to fix this for days and it´s very important for me to solve this.
For those who might wonder, this is the system:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeSLB.png)

with the k_i´s being variables described as:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eI4tb.png)

I already tried fixing the return of the function, changing the number of variables, and defining them in other ways, but nothing worked yet. It always raises the same error for some reason... I expect solving this part to be able to plot the results as graphics, but I can do this, I´m only strugling with solving this system

Comment: Per the documentation of `solv_ivp`, *"The calling signature is fun(t, y). Here t is a scalar,"*. (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html) So the first argument that `f` receives is a scalar, but the code of that function assumes that first argument will be a 6-element tuple - hence the error you see. At first sight, it could just be that the function signature should be `def f(t, X, m, g, alpha, I1, I3, d1, d2, r1, r2, mu)` - i.e. switch the first two params around - but I haven't looked in enough detail to be 100% sure of that.

Comment: wow, it fixed the type error :o, thx for that but it raised another error:( UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'phi_dot' where it is not associated with a value i really dont understand this raising because phi_dot is supposed to be a variable, isnt it?

Comment: So the code sets `phi_dot = omega3`. But there are references to `phi_dot` **before** that, so at that point it doesn't have a value and you get the error. You might just need to re-order the lines of code here.

Comment: man, it worked well here, thanks a lot:)))))) and sorry for the basic errors I commited there

Comment: great comment by @slothrop.   i should add that if you are learning python (or any other language) it is important to understand the error messages - they are really helpful.